# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Tags: gpu

I'm running an AWS EC2 g2.2xlarge instance with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I'd like to observe the GPU utilization while training my TensorFlow models.
I get an error trying to run 'nvidia-smi'.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-213:/etc/alternatives$ cd /usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-213:/usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin$ ls
nvidia-bug-report.sh     nvidia-debugdump     nvidia-xconfig
nvidia-cuda-mps-control  nvidia-persistenced
nvidia-cuda-mps-server   nvidia-smi
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-213:/usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin$ ./nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.


ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-213:/usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia 
ii  nvidia-346                                            352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-346
ii  nvidia-346-dev                                        346.46-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-346-uvm                                        346.96-0ubuntu0.0.1                                 amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-346
ii  nvidia-352                                            375.26-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-375
ii  nvidia-375                                            375.39-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 375.39
ii  nvidia-375-dev                                        375.39-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                                       375.26-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-346                                 352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-352
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-352                                 375.26-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-375
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-375                                 375.39-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                          0.6.2.1                                             amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                       375.26-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-213:/usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GL [GRID K520] (rev a1)
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-213:/usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin$ 

$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Cirrus Logic GD 5446 
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK104GL [GRID K520] 
           X.org: 1.15.1 driver: N/A tty size: 80x24 Advanced Data: N/A out of X

$  lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446
    Subsystem: XenSource, Inc. Device 0001
    Kernel driver in use: cirrus
00:03.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GL [GRID K520] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1014
00:1f.0 Unassigned class [ff80]: XenSource, Inc. Xen Platform Device (rev 01)
```

I followed these instructions to install CUDA 7 and cuDNN:

```
$sudo apt-get -q2 update
$sudo apt-get upgrade
$sudo reboot
```

=======================================================================

Post reboot, update the initramfs by running '$sudo update-initramfs -u'

Now, please edit the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file to blacklist nouveau. Open the file in an editor and insert the following lines at the end of the file.

blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off

Save and exit from the file.

Now install the build essential tools and update the initramfs and reboot again as below:

```
$sudo apt-get install linux-{headers,image,image-extra}-$(uname -r) build-essential
$sudo update-initramfs -u
$sudo reboot
```

========================================================================

Post reboot, run the following commands to install Nvidia.

```
$sudo wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/7_0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_7.0.28_linux.run
$sudo chmod 700 ./cuda_7.0.28_linux.run
$sudo ./cuda_7.0.28_linux.run
$sudo update-initramfs -u
$sudo reboot
```

========================================================================

Now that the system has come up, verify the installation by running the following.

```
$sudo modprobe nvidia
$sudo nvidia-smi -q | head`enter code here`
```

You should see the output like 'nvidia.png'.

Now run the following commands.
$

```
cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
$make
$./deviceQuery
```

However, 'nvidia-smi' still doesn't show GPU activity while Tensorflow is training models:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-48:~$ ipython
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally



ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-48:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Mar 30 05:45:26 2017       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 346.46     Driver Version: 346.46         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520           Off  | 0000:00:03.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   35C    P0    38W / 125W |     10MiB /  4095MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What worked for me was to run: `nvidia-settings` and choose NVIDIA GPU (Performance/On-Demand on your preference). It was previously set to Intel.

Answer (score 59):

I solved "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver" on my ASUS laptop with GTX 950m and Ubuntu 18.04 by disabling Secure Boot Control from BIOS.

Comment: Works for me. Now I can use CUDA again.

Comment: Worked on Dell Inspiron 7460 with 940MX. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot worked for Acer Aspire VN7 with Geforce-950M.

Comment: I don't think so it's good idea to disable the secure boot.you can enroll into MOK (Machine owner key) then you do not need to disable the Secure boot.

Comment: How can I achieve that? Enroll into MOK and not disable secure boot?

Comment: Works for me. With msi gl 63rc

Comment: During the Driver installation I did enrol MOK. A week after using my machine, somehow, it stopped working. Not sure why. Does anyone knows of another way to fix it, or at least investigate why this is happening?

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot Control did not solve the issue. I am just stuck with this.

Comment: I also had the MOK enrollment while installing the driver and the installation wizard (terminal logs) told me I was going to use it but it didn't work eventually so I had to disable the SECURE BOOT as you mentioned and it solved my issue.

Comment: This worked for me on an Azure linux VM. In the Azure portal for the VM, I had to click on security type, uncheck "Enable secure boot" which restarted the VM. After that, `nvidia-smi` worked fine.

Answer (score 24):

Run the following to get the right NVIDIA driver :

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Then pick the right  and run:

```
sudo apt install <version>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on 5.17.3

Comment: Worked for me! Installed driver nvidia-driver-515 (shown as distro non-free recommended).

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 18):

In my case none of the above solutions didn't help:

Root cause: incompatible version of gcc

Solution:

```
1. sudo apt install --reinstall gcc
2. sudo apt-get --purge -y remove 'nvidia*'
3  sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450 
4. sudo reboot
```

System: AWS EC2 18.04 instance

Solution source: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-in-ubuntu-18-04/68288/4

Comment: My machine suddenly stopped showing NVIDIA card after update. This helped me fix. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for my workstation too, not any cloud instance.

Comment: surprisingly worked for me with 550 driver version on vds. No security boot manipulations required. thx

Answer (score 11):

I am working with a AWS DeepAMI P2 instance and suddenly I found that Nvidia-driver command doesn't working and GPU is not found torch or tensorflow library. Then I have resolved the problem in the following way,

Run `nvcc --version` if it doesn't work

Then run the following

`apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

Hopefully that will solve the problem.

Comment: This works for me. In my case, a reboot is needed in order for nvidia-smi works again.

Comment: And if it does work?

Answer (score 9):

I was getting the same error on my Ubuntu 16.04 (Linux 4.14 kernel) in Google Compute Engine with K80 GPU. I upgraded the kernel to 4.15 from 4.14 and boom the problem was solved. Here is how I upgraded my Linux kernel from 4.14 to 4.15:

```
Step 1:
Check the existing kernel of your Ubuntu Linux:

uname -a

Step 2:

Ubuntu maintains a website for all the versions of kernel that have 
been released. At the time of this writing, the latest stable release 
of Ubuntu kernel is 4.15. If you go to this 
link: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/, you will 
see several links for download.

Step 3:

Download the appropriate files based on the type of OS you have. For 64 
bit, I would download the following deb files:

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-
4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-
4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-image-
4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb

Step 4:

Install all the downloaded deb files:

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Step 5:
Reboot your machine and check if the kernel has been updated by:
uname -a
```

You should see that your kernel has been upgraded and hopefully nvidia-smi should work.

Comment: This worked for me and the nvidia-390 driver, it `modprobe`s now, I updated from kernel 4.4.0 to 4.15.0.

Comment: After wasting 4+ hours, this one solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did you upgrade to 4.14 (as stated in the text) or to 4.15 (as shown in the code)? I'm running 4.15 and have the same issue

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Looks like there was some typo. Just edited it

Comment: This helped me for amazon server 16.04. nvidia-driver = 410, cuda 10.0

Answer (score 9):

Double check if you've the right permission to `/dev/nvidiactl` device or maybe it does exist at all.

```
$ strace nvidia-smi
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/nvidiactl", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Make sure `nvidia-persistenced` service is installed, up and running:

```
nvidia-persistenced --version
sudo systemctl start nvidia-persistenced
sudo systemctl status nvidia-persistenced
tail /var/log/syslog # When failed.
journalctl -xeu nvidia-persistenced.service
```

<sup>See: [Who creates /dev/nvidia0 and /dev/nvidiactl?](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/who-creates-dev-nvidia0-and-dev-nvidiactl/108272)</sup>

You may try to create the device manually by:

```
sudo modprobe -abq nvidia
sudo nvidia-modprobe -c 0 -u
nvidia-smi -L
```

---

In my case, I had the following error in syslog after restarting `nvidia-persistenced` service:

> NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for X device(s).
> This can occur when a driver such as: **nouveau**, rivafb, nvidiafb or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of the NVIDIA device(s).
> Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting driver(s).

The solution was to blacklist the `nouveau` driver, by adding the following lines into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file:

```
# Blacklist nouveau.
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

Then `reboot` the system.

<sup>See: [How to remove Nouveau kernel driver (fix Nvidia install error)](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/85-How-to-remove-Nouveau-kernel-driver-Nvidia-install-error.html).</sup>

Answer (score 5):

My system version: ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

- I solved this by generate a new MOK and enroll it into shim.
- Without disable of Secure Boot, although it also really works for me.
- Simply execute this command and follow what it suggests:

  ```
  sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
  ```

According to ubuntu's wiki:
[How can I do non-automated signing of drivers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot)

Comment: it says NO MOK found.

Comment: @Stepan Yakovenko  I just sticktly did what the link recommends, and everything went well. But now I don't use ubuntu,  because it's not comfortable for me to develop softs on it. I also have tried manjaro, but now I use win10 again. Maybe I'll use linux later. Sorry for not helping you.

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 20.04 or later, try installing the NVIDIA driver:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then

```
sudo reboot
```

As per these instructions:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

If you get an error like:

```
sudo: ubuntu-drivers: command not found
```

Then you might need to install first:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

Comment: This fixed it for me.  My issue was after upgrading from 21 to 22, for some reason nvidia drivers didn't upgrade with it.

Comment: DON'T! This made my system unusable (and after that I've realized is deprecated)

Comment: Tried different methods to install the driver on a Ubuntu Virtual Machine, but this approach worked the best. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 4):

What I found to fix the issue regardless of kernel version, was taking the WGET options and having apt install them.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Driver Version: 390.138 on Ubuntu server 18.04.4

Comment: This comment should be higher.

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstall Nvidia drivers correctly, if you use ubuntu..

First emove everything about Nvidia and Cuda

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'
```

Then run the next line

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

After that, download the [latestrun](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) file from the [Nvidia site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) according to your target platform, your architecture, etc. like this: (the style of the website could change)

[image]

Then the site will give you the commands to run for installing the Nvidia drivers, like this

[image]

In my case were:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Run those commands to install the Nvidia drivers, accept if needed to upgrade the current, or install from scratch. then the error should be fixed.

I hope it would help you, good luck!

References: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver-make-sure-that-the-latest-nvidia-driver-is-installed-and-running/197141

Answer (score 2):

I just want to thank @Heapify for providing a practical answer and update his answer because the attached links are not up-to-date.

**Step 1:**
Check the existing kernel of your Ubuntu Linux:

```
uname -a
```

**Step 2:**

Ubuntu maintains a website for all the versions of kernel that have 
been released. At the time of this writing, the latest stable release 
of Ubuntu kernel is 4.15. If you go to this 
link: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/, you will 
see several links for download.

**Step 3:**

Download the appropriate files based on the type of OS you have. For 64 
bit, I would download the following deb files:

```
// UP-TO-DATE 2019-03-18
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.15/linux-image-4.15.0-041500-generic_4.15.0-041500.201802011154_amd64.deb
```

**Step 4:**

Install all the downloaded deb files:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**Step 5:**

Reboot your machine and check if the kernel has been updated by:

```
uname -aenter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Just use this commands

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue on GE Force-920 M Nvidia chip. Initially the nvidia driver version installed was 510 which is not compatible with ubuntu 18. So, I removed that and installed the 470 version, now it's working perfectly.

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-driver-510`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-470`

Answer (score 1):

I tried above solutions but only the below worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-384 libcuda1-384 nvidia-opencl-icd-384
sudo reboot
```

credit --> https://deeptalk.lambdalabs.com/t/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver/148

Answer (score 1):

for all the other that have the same problem, and all of them solutions not work, well, here its the solution to me, just disable the security boot, and reinstall again the driver.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was similar to what @chaotux said, updating the kernel headers and development packages:
`$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

However, I would like to offer a less try-random-commands-from-stackoverflow approach, which is to read and follow CUDA installation guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the NVIDIA 367.57 driver and CUDA 7.5 with Tensorflow on the g2.2xlarge Ubuntu 14.04LTS instance. 
e.g.
nvidia-graphics-drivers-367_367.57.orig.tar

Now the GRID K520 GPU is working while I train tensorflow models:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-70:~$ nvidia-smi
Sat Apr  1 18:03:32 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520           Off  | 0000:00:03.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P8    43W / 125W |   3800MiB /  4036MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2254    C   python                                        3798MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-70:~/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GRID K520"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 7.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 4036 MBytes (4232052736 bytes)
  ( 8) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     1536 CUDA Cores
  GPU Max Clock rate:                            797 MHz (0.80 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             2500 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Maximum Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)         1D=(65536), 2D=(65536, 65536), 3D=(4096, 4096, 4096)
  Maximum Layered 1D Texture Size, (num) layers  1D=(16384), 2048 layers
  Maximum Layered 2D Texture Size, (num) layers  2D=(16384, 16384), 2048 layers
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)
  Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 2 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     No
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Domain ID / Bus ID / location ID:   0 / 0 / 3
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 8.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GRID K520
Result = PASS
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above helped for me.

I am using **Kubernetes** on **Google Cloud** with **tesla k-80 gpu**.

Follow along this guide to ensure you installed everything correctly:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus

I was missing few important things:

1. Installing NVIDIA GPU device drivers On your **NODES**. To do this use:

For COS node:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/cos/daemonset-preloaded.yaml`

For UBUNTU node:

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-accelerators/master/nvidia-driver-installer/ubuntu/daemonset-preloaded.yaml`

Make sure an update was rolled to your nodes. Restart them if upgrades are off.

2. I use this image **nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu16.04** in my docker
3. You have to set gpu limit! This is the only way the node driver can communicate with the pod. In your yaml configuration add this under your container:

   ```
   resources:
     limits:
       nvidia.com/gpu: 1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

One important fact about NVIDIA drivers that is not very well known is that its built is done by DKMS. This allows automatic rebuild in case of kernel upgrade, this happens on system startup. Because of that, it's quite easy to miss error messages, especially if you're working on cloud VM, or server without an additional IPMI/management interface. However, it's possible to trigger DKMS build just executing `dkms autoinstall` right after packages installation. If this fails then you'll have a meaningful error message about missing dependency or what so ever. If `dkms autoinstall` builds modules correctly you can simply load it by `modprobe` - there is no need to reboot the system (which is often used as a way to trigger DKMS rebuild).
You can check an example [here](http://NVIDIA-SMI%20has%20failed%20because%20it%20couldn%E2%80%99t%20communicate%20with%20the%20NVIDIA%20driver)

Answer (score 0):

It may happen after your Linux kernel update, if you entered this error, you can rebuild your nvidia driver using the following command to fix:

1. Firstly, you need to have `dkms`,  which can automatically regenerate new modules after kernel version changes.
   `sudo apt-get install dkms`
2. Secondly, rebuild your nvidia driver. Here my nvidia driver version is 440.82, if you have installed before, you could check your installed version on `/usr/src`.
   `sudo dkms build -m nvidia -v 440.82`
3. Lastly, reinstall nvidia driver. And then reboot your computer.
   `sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v 440.82`

Now you can check to see if you can use it by `sudo nvidia-smi`.

Comment: When you say "reinstall the driver" what do you mean? Run the original installer?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by re-installing CUDA:

```sh
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.1.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-1-local_11.1.0-455.23.05-1_amd64.deb
echo "md5sum: $(md5sum cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-1-local_11.1.0-455.23.05-1_amd64.deb)"
echo "correct: 056de5e03444cce506202f50967b0016"
dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-1-local_11.1.0-455.23.05-1_amd64.deb
apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-1-local/7fa2af80.pub
apt-get -qq update
apt-get -qq -y install cuda
rm cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-1-local_11.1.0-455.23.05-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling on this issue for two days, sharing my solution here in case anyone may need it.

The VMs that I'm using are Standard N-series GPU server with 2 K80 cards on Azure platform. With Ubuntu 18.04 OS installed.

Apparently there is an update of linux kernel several days before I came across this issue, and after the update the driver stopped working.

At first, I did purge and re-install as above replies suggested. Nothing works. Out of sudden(I don't remember why I wanted to do it), I updated the default gcc and g++ version on one of my VM as following.

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 90
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9 90
```

Then I purged the nvidia softwares and reinstall it as instructed in official document(please choose the correct one for your system: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal) again.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

Then the nvidia-smi command finally worked again.

PS:

If you are using Azure linux VM like me. The recommended way to install CUDA is actually by enabling "NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension" in the Azure portal (of course, after you have configured the correct gcc version).

I have tried this way on my another VM and It works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no linux expert, but I did the following things and it worked out well for me:

1. Go to https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx download the appropriate driver.
2. Transfer the .run file to the ec2 system, (I used filezilla for transferring the file)
3. cd into the .run file path
4. Execute chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-XXX.XXX.XX.run
5. Execute ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-XXX.XXX.XX.run
6. Execute sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

#### Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia* && sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

- chmod 700 means you can do anything with the file or directory and other users have no access to it at all

1. First run below command:

   chmod 700 ./Nvidia.xyz.run
2. Start the Nvidia driver

   sudo ./Nvidia.xyx.run

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In /usr/src:

```
ls
```

[image]

Find **your nvidia driver version** (e.g., nvidia-535.129.03), then:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v 535.129.03
```

If the version has `srv` (e.g., nvidia-srv-535.129.03), then add `srv` before the version series: `sudo dkms install -m nvidia -v srv-535.129.03`.
Problem solved:

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: @Chris Hi, Chirs. I have aleady typed the text version of my code in the answer. The image is nothing about the code/data/errors, but just results. Without seeing these images, the problem can still be solved by following my typed codes.

Comment: Why would this only apply to the code? If the results are an important part of your answer, they should also be provided as text.

Answer (score 0):

This week, also I faced with the same issue. I disable the secure boot option from boot setting and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -17):

Try pulling out the NVIDIA graphics card and reinserting it.

Comment: How could this possibly help?

Comment: How do you do this on an AWS instance ?

Comment: This is not a SNES cartridge.