# Error: NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gpu, nvidia

The NVIDIA-SMI is throwing this error:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
>   driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
>   running

I purged NVIDIA and installed it again following steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760997/how-to-recover-from-a-nvidia-fail-on-ubuntu-16-04).

My device specs are as follows:

- Server with a Tesla M40
- Running on Ubuntu 16.04
- Kernel version Linux 4.4.0-116-generic x86_64
- Driver: nvidia-384

Can someone please help in solving the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: this answer is from 2018 and works for Ubuntu 16.04, which is very much out-of-date. Don't try this on recent Ubuntu versions.

Try

1. Download the driver from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/tesla/375.66/nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604_375.66-1_amd64.deb&lang=us&type=Tesla)
2. `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` - To remove your current installations
3. `dpkg -i nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604_375.66-1_amd64.deb` - installing what you downloaded earlier
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers`

After this, go on and reboot your computer.
When it's up again, the `nvidia-smi` command should run smoothly

Comment: I followed above steps and now when i type "nvidia-smi" its throwing following error "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_387': Exec format error
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

Comment: which card do you have? and which nvidia driver you installed?

Comment: I have added server specifications.

Comment: I would try installing nvidia-375,  http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/118962/en-us - just purge again and this time install `sudo apt-get install nvidia-375`

Comment: **sudo apt-get install nvidia-375** is trying to install both nvidia-375 and nvidia-384.  **nvidia-smi** is giving the same error even after installing nvidia-375.

Comment: Last try, I have updated the answer, try and following it

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you, so others will too :)

Answer (score 9):

The issue might due to a confirmed "bug" in 4.4.0-116 patch. I ran into the same issue with nvidia-390. If you still want to use a newer version of Nvidia-driver, I followed the instructions [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8/+bug/1750937/comments/57) and managed to solve the problem. In general, use the following steps:

1. If you cannot login to the desktop and fall into to the fail-loop, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to login into the command line mode.
2. Check if the version of gcc is outdated, if so, update it: `gcc --version`
3. If the gcc version is 5+, uninstall the nvidia driver first: `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-390`
4. Purge the 4.4.0-116 kernel: `sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-116-generic`
5. Reinstall the kernel: `sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-signed-generic`
6. Reinstall the nvidia-390: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`
7. Check if the problem is solved by `modinfo nvidia-390 -k 4.4.0-116-generic | grep vermagic`, make sure **retpoline** shows up this time
8. Reboot: `sudo reboot`

Hope this works for you and other people who run into the same issue. The post in the forum saved my weekend.

Comment: I'm getting error at step 7. modinfo: ERROR: Module alias nvidia-387 not found.
aerin@capa:~$ libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/modules.dep.bin'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, that step's command should depend on your version of  NVIDIA driver, I forgot to change the version from the other post, edited now.

Answer (score 2):

to download latest driver as of this answer:

```
    sudo apt install libnvidia-compute-435 libnvidia-compute-435
    sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-435 nvidia-dkms-435 nvidia-kernel-source-435         
    nvidia-utils-435 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435 libnvidia-ifr1-435 
    sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435
    sudo reboot
```

and then:

```
    nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this on Google Colab, just go to Runtime > Change Runtime Type > select GPU. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate topic.

There is no single problem responsible for this message, so there is no single solution.

This Link has more solutions and is older:

[NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984743/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver)